# Installing certificate on IIS 7 for WCF security

Tags: iis-7, certificate, wcf-security

I want to install a temporary certificate for my WCF service which installed in an IIS 7 server. How do I do that? is there any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-signed certificate, see [scottgu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx) for help.